# The best way to multiple check is in array in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i want the best way to check if a value is in array in angular, this test is verified 2 time in my html. This is a very simple example to explain my problem:

in scope:

```
$scope.flaggedItems = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
$scope.items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
```

in html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
    <p ng-if="flaggedItems.indexOf(item)>-1">flagged !</p>
    <p ng-if="flaggedItems.indexOf(item)==0">not flagged.</p>
</div>
```

With this solution, i call 2 times the method "indexOf". It's bad...
So how to add a variable accessible in this html to run one time only the method indexOf. Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)**

Try like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="index=flaggedItems.indexOf(item)">
  <p ng-if="index>-1">flagged !</p>
</div>
```